# Removing characters from Actionscript 3 Strings

Tags: arrays, string, actionscript-3

I have a text file that I read using the usual URLRequest and URLloader functions. It consists of a series of names, each separated by `\r\d`.  I want to create an array of those names, but I want to eliminate both the `\r` and the `\d`. This code does a great job at splitting the names into arrays, but it leaves the carriage return in the string.

```
names = testfile.split(String.fromCharCode(10));
```

And this leaves the new line:

```
names = testfile.split(String.fromCharCode(13));
```

I'm mainly a C/C++/assembly programmer, AS3 has some things that seem rather odd to me.  Is there a way to do this?  I've tried searching the resulting string array members but I get errors from the compiler.  Very easy to do in C/C++/assembly, but I haven't quite figured AS3 out yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a `RegExp` to do this. Something like:

```
var noLines:String = withLines.replace( /[\r\n]/g, "" );
```

That'll remove all new lines from your string; whether you want to do that before or after splitting it up to you.

If your string is in the form:

```
name1
name2
name3
```

Then you might even be able to get away with splitting using a `RegExp`:

```
var names:Array = withLines.split( /[\r\n]/ );
```

You can test out the `RegExp` provided here: http://regexr.com?38dmk (click on the replace tab and clear the replace input)

Comment: You can split with regex, but remove the bracket expression or it will split on each single occurrence of `\r` and `\n` rather than on `\r\n`. `testfile.split(/\r\n/);`

Comment: good point, the only reason I added the `[]` was because RegExr wasn't matching anything when I set `\r\n`. You might be able to get away with just a `/\r/` or a `/\n/`, or event `/\r\n?/`, depending on the file in question, and how far you want to delve into the bowels of regular expressions :)

Comment: You both got it right.  I can either take the array strings and use replace or split with /\r\n/.